# Macro to copy multiple rows from one worksheet to another and then copy the headings into copied columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I am new to macros and I have developed this macro that allows me to take rows that has data in them from cells B-G from Workseet "master 1" starting from row 11. I take this data and then copy it into worksheet 2 "Knowledge database" in the next empty row and paste the data into Column J.

The macro kind of works in that it does what I want it do but it seems to paste the data in the same worksheet-"Master 1" rather than the other worksheet "knowledge Database".

I have labelled the sheets correctly so I dont know why it wont go onto the next sheet. I have obviously missed something and would appreicate some help please :)

```
Sub Macro2()

    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
    TheLastrow = ActiveCell.Row

    For i = 11 To TheLastrow

        If Cells(i, 2).Value >= "0" Then
            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 7)).Select
            Selection.Cut

            Dim b As Integer, c As Integer

            b = Worksheets.Count

            For c = 1 To b
                If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(c).Name = "Test run" Then
                    Worksheets("knowledge database").Select
                End If
            Next c

            erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 10).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```